# Issue with hex data being sent out of a serial port

Tags: python-2.7, serial-port

I am really hoping someone can help me with this issue, I have been working on it for 3 days and its driving me insane now.

I have two linux based devices connected over serial, one is an embedded device the other is a pc type device. I have some python code on the PC device that currently, successfully reads messages sent by the embedded device (hence the serial settings are correct).

However I now need to send commands back to the embedded device and this is what i am struggling with, I have a data tap on the serial line so i can see the data being sent / received.

When I send the string "\x2a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x57\x78\xD6\x81\x00\x01\x00\x8D\x54" out of the serial port, on the serial data tap I see only "EF F7 FF FF".

Please see the code below:

```
import serial

serialport = serial.Serial(port=self.device,
                                       baudrate=self.baudrate,
                                       bytesize=self.bytesize,
                                       parity=self.parity,
                                       stopbits=self.stopbits,
                                       timeout=0)

data = "\x2a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x57\x78\xD6\x81\x00\x01\x00\x8D\x54"
serialport.write(data)
serialport.flushOutput()
```

Comment: Does your serial data tap show the correct data on the commands the embedded device is sending?

Answer (score 0):

This is now resolved, turned out to be a couple of issues the customer neglected to tell me that unless the embedded device is in engineering mode it will ignore commands. Also the data tap had a dip switch set incorrectly, so there was nothing wrong with my code.  Thanks to Shane for making me question the hardware and not my code !